# Using bell state shared between two nodes to perform a CNOT gate between different qubits across the nodes

Tags: entanglement

Consider a distributed quantum computer, where two qubit gates can be performed between qubits in the same individual quantum information processor (QIP), but not in separate ones. Suppose each QIP has an additional qubit that is not used for logic, but rather communication. We will assume that it is possible to easily generate a bell state from any two communication qubits (this could be done using entanglement swapping and a flying qubit). My question is, what is the most efficient way to exploit such a bell state to perform a CNOT gate between two logical qubits in different QIPs, assuming two qubit gates may be performed between the logical and communication qubits.

Obviously we could tediously perform a teleportation one way, perform the CNOT gate then generate another bell state and perform a teleportation the other way, but I feel like there must be a more efficient way than this.